# How to make routing path with nested dynamic routes

Tags: angular, nativescript, router

I have a module in the app with next routing:
Two tabs with compared items (let's call them cats and dogs).
One tab with dynamic list of cats, 1 tab with dynamic list of dogs.

This is the routing:

```
export const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: PetTabsComponent,
    resolve: {
        items: PetResolver,
    },
    children: [

        {
            path: 'dogList/:list',
            component: PetListComponent,
            outlet: 'dogOutlet',
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'details/:id',
                    component: PetDetailsComponent,
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            path: 'catList/:list',
            component: PetListComponent,
            outlet: 'catOutlet',
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'details/:id',
                    component: PetDetailsComponent,
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

This is HTML with outlets (I use Nativescript so syntax is a little different)

```
<Tabs>
   <TabContentItem>
       <page-router-outlet name="dogOutlet" actionBarVisibility="never"></page-router-outlet>
   </TabContentItem>
   <TabContentItem>
       <page-router-outlet name="catOutlet" actionBarVisibility="never"></page-router-outlet>
   </TabContentItem>
</Tabs>
```

This is the method in TetListComponent. When tap on the pet card we have to go to its details page

```
tapOnPet(petName) {
   this._router.navigate(
       ['./details", petName],
       {
         relativeTo: this.active
       }
   );
}
```

The problem is, I can't reach the details page from the list page. I tried different options but mostly I have the error

> : NS-ERR-HANDLER Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: <NAME_OF_PARENT_PAGE>

Also how to make path with 2 dynamic routes like

```
this._router.navigate([{
   outlets: {
      catOutlet: ["catList (with list array) /details", petName]
}}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need named router outlet for this. all you need is nested router outlet. please follow article below for same.

https://blog.devgenius.io/the-art-of-nested-router-outlets-in-angular-dafb38245a30

Comment: Seems there is different case. I need two outlets on one page.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?